# Why Do Laravel Blade Templates Have Both @yield and @extend Directives?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-5.6

I don't understand why there are two complementary, but also possibly contradictory directives with Laravel templates. When building views, is it just a matter of being robust, or does it create more options, or is it something else?

From the official documentation, a container defines `@sections` and "pulls" in content from other view fragments using `@yield` statements... right?

```
<!-- Stored in resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php -->
```

```php
<html>
    <head>
        <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @section('sidebar')
            This is the master sidebar.
        @show
        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And then the child component is used by saying "wrap me" in a master layout, using the `@extends` statement.

```
<!-- Stored in resources/views/child.blade.php -->
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title', 'Page Title')
```

Inevitably this increases the risk of them sometimes contradicting each other?

Answer (score 0):

Well, `@extends` is used just for saying - use this template as base one and `@yield` is saying - here you should put content of section with given name.

So as you showed here, you can create base template with a lot of HTML markup but some parts are dynamic so you use `@yield` here and then you can create multiple child templates that will put some real value in those places - all those templates will extend the parent one and define what should be put in place of each `@yield`

Comment: OK... I think I'm following you.... butlet me ask you this. Is there a scenario where things become contradictory? The "container" says insert a piece here, and the piece extends a totally different container? I imagine it would create a bit of a dog's breakfast.